# "make" error when bundling a packge

Tags: make

I m trying to install soundtouch package but I m having some problems

I m following their instruction on how to compile soundtouch after unzipping the file.
It tells me to

`./configure` -

Configures the SoundTouch package for the local environment.

`make` -

Builds the SoundTouch library & SoundStretch utility.

`make install` -

Installs the SoundTouch & BPM libraries to `/usr/local/lib` and SoundStretch utility to `/usr/local/bin`. Please notice that 'root' privileges may be required to install the binaries to the destination locations.

I did the first step but when I run make, it gives me errors.

```
james@Bum-Ho:~/pitch shifter/soundtouch$ make
cd . && automake-1.10 --foreign 
/bin/bash: line 4: automake-1.10: command not found
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

What could be the problem? I looked up to see if I had automake installed and I did so I dont understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to implement difficult compilation procedures to install `soundtouch`. it is in official ubuntu Repository. Can be installed with the package `libsoundtouch0`.

```
sudo apt-get install libsoundtouch0 libsoundtouch-dev
```

Comment: I already have that packaged installed in my ubuntu but it wont run. The package I m trying use is a python wrapper of Soundtouch. When I run setup.py to install this wrapper it says that Soundtouch.h file is not installed which led to think that soundtouch was not installed in my ubuntu

Comment: `Soundtouch.h` file  is provided by the package `libsoundtouch-dev`. I included it in the answer.